# SQL Server 2008 Full Text Index issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, ssms

I am new to SQL Server 2008 Full Text index function. I am learning from this tutorial, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLServer2K8FullTextSearh.aspx. I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

In the first step of the tutorial, it is mentioned that I need to "Create a Full-Text Catalog", but I did not find the New Full-Text Catalog dialog in SQL Server Management Studio, could anyone help to point where to find it please?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it through the GUI.

You can expand the node for the database of interest then expand "Storage" and there is a "Full Text Catalogs" node there.

Right click that to bring up the "New Full Text Catalog" option.